# finding array element in an object

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
"features" : {
    "en" : [ 
        {
            "translatable" : true,
            "capacity " : [ 
                "128GB", 
                "256GB"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "translatable" : true,
            "material  " : [ 
                "Glass", 
                "Aluminium"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am finding 'capacity': '128GB' when I am using this query

```
db.getCollection('products').find({
    'features.en' : {
        $elemMatch : {
            'capacity' : {
                $in : ['128GB']
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But not fetching.
If i query for 'translatable':true

```
db.getCollection('products').find({
    'features.en' : {
        $elemMatch : {
            'translatable' : true
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a tricky TYPO in your input document - so please check if **capacity** has a SPACE at the end

```
db.prod.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                "features.en.capacity " : "128GB"
            }
        },
    ]).pretty()
```

to get only array element that mets your criteria you can use this aggregation query:

```
db.prod.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$features.en"
        }, {
            $match : {
                "features.en.translatable" : true
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                "features.en.capacity " : "128GB"
            }
        },
    ]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, it wasn't working because of the TYPO

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

db.products.find({'features.en': { $elemMatch: {'capacity': {$elemMatch:{$in: ['128GB']}}} } })